# Rewrite URL using htaccess php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the url in my project.

For example:

`http://www.example.com/dashboard/test/` to `http://dashboard.example.com/index.php`

Also I want to do it for:

`http://www.example.com/dashboard/test2/` to `http://dashboard.example.com/index.php`

Can anyone tell me the idea to rewrite the url?

Comment: When you say "**rewrite from A to B**", it means when you type in **A** in your browser's URL address bar, you get served the content at **B**, but **A** remains in your address bar. Is that what you want?

Comment: `Can anyone tell me the idea to rewrite the url.` Yes. Someone is definitely able to do that. What have *you* tried?

Comment: You are on apache. Right?

Comment: Yeah, @JonLin is right.. I can purely help you about that, if you explained your question more.

Answer (score 0):

First you create a .htaccess file in your root.
Than, just put the redirect commands in it.
How to compose a .htaccess and how to create rewrite rules is explained here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files/

You will need something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dashboard.example.com/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test.*$  http://dashboard.example.com/index.php [R=301,L]
```